# Momentjs Deprecation Warning using Format

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I was wondering what the mentioned deprecated method means for my momentJS method and what change I can make to format my values correctly. I have date values in a format as such `2015-12-11 00:00:00`. And I'm trying to convert them to the proper field format `YYYY-MM-DD`. My jQuery below allows me to convert my date values in the proper format without any issues, but I receive the following warning in my console log. Any ideas what this means?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test-form-date").val( moment("{{test.testDate}}").format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
        $("#data-date-start").val( moment("{{test.testDateStart}}").format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
        $("#data-date-end").val( moment("{{test.testDateEnd}}").format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the form that is being modified:

```
<div class="test-form-header">
    <input type="date" name="testDate" id="test-form-date" value="{{test.testDate}}">
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-inline date-start">
    <label for="data-start-range">Data Date Start:</label>
    <input type="date" id="data-date-start" name="dataDateStart" value="{{test.dataDateStart}}">
</div>
<div class="form-inline date-end">
    <label for="data-end-range">Data Date End:</label>
    <input type="date" id="data-date-end" name="dataDateEnd" value="{{test.dataDateEnd}}">
</div>
```

Here is the warning to the console log:

> The specified value "Sun Dec 27 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)" does not
>   conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd". 10:60 The specified
>   value "Wed Sep 30 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" does not conform to
>   the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd". 10:64 The specified value "Thu Dec
>   03 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd". moment.js:737 Deprecation warning: moment
>   construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be
>   removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Error

> ```
> at Function.createFromInputFallback (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:746:36)
> at configFromString (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:826:32)
> at configFromInput (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:1353:13)
> at prepareConfig (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:1340:13)
> at createFromConfig (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:1307:44)
> at createLocalOrUTC (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:1385:16)
> at local__createLocal (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:1389:16)
> at utils_hooks__hooks (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js:16:29)
> at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/app/edit/10:87:38)
> at j
> ```

(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:26925)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code.

```
moment.createFromInputFallback = function(config) {
  // unreliable string magic, or
  config._d = new Date(config._i);
};
$("#test-form-date").val( moment("{{test.testDate}}").format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
```

The error happens because,

> moment construction using a non-iso string is deprecated.

For more details read, [Be careful when falling back to Date constructor](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407)

Answer (score 0):

moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;

Adding this after import moment module hide that warnings